# Terraform remote-exec Failed to upload script: scp: /tmp permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am heavily struggling with the local-exec by Terraform.
I am deploying a an EC2 instance with an own built AMI from amazon-linux-2.

I have this code:

```
locals {
  ssh_user_home = "/home/ec2-user"
}

resource "null_resource" "rerun" {
  triggers = {
    rerun = uuid()
  }


  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/sources"
    destination = "${local.ssh_user_home}/tmp"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "${var.aws_ssh_user}"
      private_key = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.kibana_proxy_ssh_value.secret_string}"
      host        = "${aws_instance.logstash.private_ip}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./creds"
    destination = "${local.ssh_user_home}/tmp"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "${var.aws_ssh_user}"
      private_key = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.kibana_proxy_ssh_value.secret_string}"
      host        = "${aws_instance.logstash.private_ip}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [

      "cd ${local.ssh_user_home}/tmp",
      "cp creds/.htpasswd.${var.aws_env} creds/.htpasswd",
      "bash -x sources/ansible.sh ${var.es_fqdn} ${var.kibana_domain}",
      # "rm -r /tmp/creds/",
      # "rm -r /tmp/sources/",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "${var.aws_ssh_user}"
      private_key = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.kibana_proxy_ssh_value.secret_string}"
      host        = "${aws_instance.logstash.private_ip}"
      #script_path = "${local.ssh_user_home}"
    }
  }
}
```

There is always this error:

```
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   Host: 10.135.202.29
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   User: ec2-user
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   Password: false
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   Private key: true
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
module.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
mmodule.logstash-instance.null_resource.rerun (remote-exec): Connected!

Failed to upload script: scp: /tmp: Permission denied
```

No idea what I am doing wrong since terraform uses `ec2-user` as user and everything is copied into `/home/ec2-user/tmp`

Comment: `script_path = "${local.ssh_user_home}"` should be a path to a file, not to a directory.

Comment: ok. I adjusted my code since I need the remote-exec to execute the commands defined in inline=

Comment: So does it work now as expected?

Comment: Nope, because I have this permission denied issue. The problem is the remote-exec passage.

Comment: Could you try a one-line, static inline script to confirm that the inline contents aren't causing this?

Comment: Tried "sudo cp /tmp/creds/.htpasswd.${var.aws_env} creds/.htpasswd"... still the issue

Comment: A workaround might be to write the script file locally, copy it to remote, and remote-exec the script. Even if that fails, perhaps the error generated will give more of a clue what's causing the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the issue. The amazon linux 2 is hardened in a way that it does not allow ssh from an external source out of the box. I did not find a solution to soften this restriction, but I made use of user_data (with cloud-init which means the ec2 instance runs the user_data script after reboot) and everything works now :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you need to do a chmod+x to the file you want to run. The file has no permissions to be run as a script once you copy there.

> provisioner "remote-exec" {

```
connection {
  type        = "ssh"
  user        = "root"
  host        = hcloud_server.derms_lab_server[count.index].ipv4_address
  private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
}

inline = [
  "chmod 700 /tmp/get_up_grafana_container.sh",
  "/tmp/get_up_grafana_container.sh"
]
```

}